# write a sql statement to count the data that meet a certain condition in every minute in TDengine

Tags: query

I have a sql statement in time-series database TDengine.

```
select count(*) as count 
from iot.things_model_meters 
where model_identifier = 'online'  
interval(1m) sliding(1m);
```

Like this statement will only count the data meet certain condition within 1 minute, but what I want is to count the data in every minute. What should I do?

Comment: "*count the eligible data in all data meet a condition in every minute*" - Can you clarify what you mean by this?...Adding example data and expected results to your Post would be very helpful here.

Comment: sorry for the expression, just modified it.

Comment: No problem, but I'm still not sure I understand. Could you please provide a data example and expected results?